# Named Structures in C++ Unions

Tags: c++, gcc, struct, forward-declaration, unions

In C++, I'm trying to create a specialized point class as a union, like so:

```
union point
{
  struct { float x, y, z; };
  float val[3];
  float operator[](unsigned i) { return val[i]; }
};
```

So that I can access the point as an array or as multiple points, for readability.

However, let's say that I want to generalise this a bit:

```
template<unsigned n>
  union point
  {
    struct { float ???; };
    float val[n];
    float operator[](unsigned i) { return val[i]; }
  };
```

What can I put for `???`?  I could have `x`, `x, y`, `x, y, z`, or `x, y, z, w` depending on what `n` is.  Solution?  Forward declarations!

```
template<unsigned n>
  union point
  {
    struct coords;
    float val[n];
    float operator[](unsigned i) { return val[i]; }
  };

template<>
  struct point::coords<3>
  {
    float x, y, z;
  };

// ...
```

But this doesn't appear to work.  Under the GCC 4.6, it compiles, however, whenever that I try to use the members, like so:

```
point<3> val;
val.x;
```

I get the error:

```
error: ‘union point<3>’ has no member named ‘x’
```

Even if I change `val.x` to `val.coords::x`, I still get the error:

```
error: ‘union point<3>::coords’ is not a base of ‘union point<3>’
```

Adding `using coords;` in the union definition didn't help, either.

Is there any way to accomplish this under the GCC 4.6?  Is there a different method of doing this?  Is it even possible?

Comment: If you have to specialize each template instance, why not just declare 4 different unions (sans templates) and be done with it?

Comment: Are you interested in solutions to "[accessing] the point as an array or as multiple points, for readability" in a more general sense too, or is the union stuff necessary?

Comment: Luc - The main reason is that 99% of the time, x, y, z, and w will be used as member accessors, but I still want to allow the ability to easily iterate through the points' values without having to do a hackish pointer typecast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using **variadic macro** to define your `union<N>` templates.

```
template<unsigned int N>
union point; // declared and undefined

#define DECLARE_POINT(NUM, ...) \
template<> \
union point<NUM> \
{ \
  struct { float __VA_ARGS__; }; \
  float val[NUM]; \
}

#undef DECLARE_POINT
```

Having done this, you can simply declare/define your various combinations for coordinates (before `#undef` in this case):

```
DECLARE_POINT(1, x);
DECLARE_POINT(2, x, y);
DECLARE_POINT(3, x, y, z);
```

that is equivalent to,

```
template<> union point<1> { struct { float x; }; float val[1]; };
template<> union point<2> { struct { float x, y; }; float val[2]; };
template<> union point<3> { struct { float x, y, z; }; float val[3]; };
```

It can be used in the same way you asked:

```
point<3> p;
p.z = 0;
```

Also, you can put a cross check using some template trickery (`static_assert`) to check the number arguments(e.g. `1,2,3,...`) match the total argument passed (e.g. `x,y,z,...`).

Answer (score 1):

This line inside your union:

```
struct coords;
```

forward-declares the type `coords`, but there's no `struct coords` field in your templated union.

Besides, only members of anonymous structures can be accessed as top-level fields of an union. For instance:

```
union foo {
    struct { // anonymous struct
        short i;
        short j;
    };
    int k;
};

foo f;
// it's possible to access the fields of the anonymous struct as if they were
// direct members of the union
f.i = 4;
f.j = 8;
std::cout << f.k;
```

I'm not sure you'll be able to do that if you only specialize the inner `struct` type.

However, this works:

```
template<unsigned n>
union point;

template<>
union point<2> {
    struct { float x, y; };
    float val[2];
};

template<>
union point<3> {
    struct { float x, y, z; };
    float val[3];
};
```

There is a number of downsides though; the main one being that you'll have to redefine `operator[]` for each version of `point`.

I know how to use templates but I'm no template god, so it's not out of question that a clever trick exists.

Comment: It should be mentioned that anonymous structs are not part of C++, but only a popular extension (and will become part of C1x, next C version; however, not of C++0x).